# Minecraft: Swapping two scoreboard values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a redstone computer, and I am done making increment value, decrement value, goto function with index, stop signal, and other small things, and all is working. I am storing the main calculation value in a scoreboard value named `Reg1`. I would like to add a `Reg0/Reg2`, and I would like to know if there is any possible way to do something like: `/scoreboard players set @p Reg1 Reg2`, or anything like that? I want to set one variable equal to another.

I do not want to have a large amount of blocks having `/testfor @p[score_Reg1 = 1]` and then `/scoreboard players set @p Reg2 1` and then doing the same with 2, then 3, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `/scoreboard players operation`:

```
/scoreboard players operation <target1> <objective1> <operation> <target2> <objective2>
```

The available `operation`s are:

> - `+=` **Addition**: increase first first score by second
> - `-=` **Subtraction**: decrease first first score by second
> - `*=` **Multiplication**: multiply the first score by the second
> - `/=` **Integer Division**: divide first score by second
> - `%=` **Modular Division**: set first score to the remainder when it's divided by the second
> - `=` **Assign**: set first score to the second
> - `<` **Min**: set first score to the min of either score
> - `>` **Max**: set first score to the max of either score
> - `><` **Swap**: swaps the scores around

What you want to do should be:

```
/scoreboard players operation @p Reg1 = @p Reg2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i solved it by making three command blocks in a chain in this order: 1. "/scoreboard players operation @p Reg0 = @p Reg1" 2. "/scoreboard players operation @p Reg1 = @p Reg2"  3. "/scoreboard players operation @p Reg2 = @p Reg0". I marked your response as accepted.